# Xubuntu 12.04 hangs when sleeping the second time

Tags: xubuntu, sleep

After booting my machine, it's able to suspend correclty the first time, with the power button flashing slowly.  I'm able to hit the button and have it come back on.  The second time however, seems to never get all the way to sleep, I'll just come in to find a blank screen with the power button showing a steady light, and I have to do a hard reboot to get it back.

Running Xubuntu 12.04, 3.2.0-25-generic kernel, P67A-G43 motherboard with 2600K processor.

Comment: I have the same issue with a i7-3770, no such issues with current fedora or debian stable. Seems to be a kernel problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by following the instructions in this forum thread:

- [Asus X54H will not suspend correctly](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916751)

After I implemented that script, everything worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.